# Froala WYSIWYG editor: how to tell a server to delete an uploaded image

Tags: froala

I am hoping to use Froala (2.6.4) in my web app and I am testing it out.

I am able to configure `imageUploadURL` and add server-side code to store images. Now if a user removes an image in the editting area, I hope to be able to delete the image from the server. However, I am not able to find any URL setting for this purpose.

Did I miss something?

Please note that I do not use Image Manager plugin.

**UPDATE**

I was not able to find any option for notifying the server of deleting an image. I do find an event called

```
froalaEditor.image.removed
```

It gets called when I remove an image. I hope this is the way to tell the server to delete an image.

Now come two more questions based on my tests.

1. When I delete an image from the editting area, my program deletes the image from the server. If a user restores it by pressing Ctrl+Z on Windows, the image shows up again in the editting area. The problem is that I need to save the image on the server. Based on my tests, the server code at `imageUploadURL` does not get called.
2. I can select and copy an area of image in an image editing tool (Paint on my Windows machine). I am able to paste it in the editing area, and it is saved on the server via `imageUploadURL`. However, the event `froalaEditor.image.removed` gets called too each time when pasting an image. Is this a bug? Please note that this event does not gets called when I drag and drop or upload an image onto the editing area.